# How to disable chrome permission popup in selenium driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, wdio-v5

Chrome version 89 and set up below setting and still not dismissing the permission popup which blocks the rest of test cases.
Any idea or workaround?
[image]

```
capabilities: [{
    
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 1,
        //
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            // to run chrome headless the following flags are required
            // (see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
            // args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
            prefs: {
                'profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups' : 1,
                'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications' : 1,
            },
            args: ['--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs',  'disable-infobars', 'disable-popup-blocking', 'disable-notifications']
        },
        // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
        // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, but, if you're using Python and the popup appears in a consistent location, you can use pyautogui to click the block or allow button and close the popup.  See sample code, below:

```
import pyautogui 

# ensure the Selenium-managed browser has the focus and will receive the click   
driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle) 

# moveTo the X and Y coordinate of the block or allow button
pyautogui.moveTo(1350, 700) 

# click the block or allow button
pyautogui.click()
```

If you need to determine the X and Y coordinate, the code below can help:

```
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```